# Self dependency in Spark 2014

Tags: ada, gnat, spark-2014

I'm trying to write the flow dependency of a procedure in Ada and Spark 2014 and the compiler give me a medium warning that

```
medium: missing dependency "null => MyBool"
medium: incorrect dependency "MyBool => MyBool"
```

Here is my .ads file:

```
SPARK_Mode (On);
package TestDep is

  pragma Elaborate_Body;

  MyBool: Boolean := False;

  procedure ToFalse with
    Global => (In_Out => MyBool),
    Depends => (MyBool =>+ null),
    Pre => (MyBool = True),
    Post => (MyBool = False);

end TestDep;
```

and in the .adb:

```
pragma SPARK_Mode (On);
package body TestDep is

  procedure ToFalse is
  begin
    MyBool := False;
  end ToFalse;

end TestDep;
```

I'm new to Ada and Spark and I'm still learning it, but from [the AdaCore documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/lrm/subprograms.html#depends-aspects) I've saw that `Depends => (X =>+ null)` should indicate that the value of `X` at the end of the procedure only depends on the value of `X` and nothing else.

Why does the compiler give me those warning ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `MyBool` is set to `False`, and thus does not depend on the initial value of `MyBool`. The `Global` should be just `Output`, not `In_Out`

Comment: Yes, MyBool must be with `Global => (Output => MyBool)`. And then `Depends => (X =>+ null)` must be `Depends => (X => null)`. If you need more information, I can write an answer to this question. But I suppose, with these two comments it is clear.